# array contains element but IndexOf returns -1

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a string array `lines` of which one item may contain the value `Mister` or `Misses`.

```
var lines = "3.3. 3 - 3 88C Mister Molitor D For Ne Les Text".Split(' ');

Console.WriteLine(lines.Contains("Mister") || lines.Contains("Misses"));
```

returns `true`. Now I want to find the index of `Mister`, respectively `Misses`, using

```
var index = lines.IndexOf("Mister");
```

*(I didn't put the code for `Misses` here for the sake of simplicity)*

**However,** index *always* is `-1` (despite the item's existence in the array). So I thought there must be something different to try (I even added `ToLower()`, which however cannot be the reason as `lines.Contains()` otherwise'd return false):

```
var index = lines.FindIndex(x => x.ToLower() == "mister");
```

**But still...** `index = -1`. This is driving me crazy! We *definitely* have the array containing the item, yet I can't find the index.

Comment: "3.3. 3 - 3 88C Misses Molitor D For Ne Les Text" this string contains the word 'Misses' but it does not contain the word 'mister'.

Comment: Please notice `IndexOf` is a method of `string` only, but here in code you're using string array. What you may look for is array's `FindIndex`. Using your code, and using 'misses' instead of 'mister' in `var index = lines.FindIndex(x => x.ToLower() == "mister");` worked for me

Comment: @DanielHollinrake please read carefully: `(I didn't put the code for Misses here for the sake of simplicity)`. `Misses` is handled exactly the same as `Mister`. I know that this is pretty much messy, but I edited the original string so that it's clear right away.

Comment: I did read carefully and I noted that your version of the string did not contain the word you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The following is `true`

```
lines.Contains("Mister") || lines.Contains("Misses")
```

because your string literal contains the word `Misses`. That being said, when you call the `IndexOf` on the `lines` passing as a parameter the `Mister` you get `-1`, because `Mister` is not contained in `lines`.

Comment: Well, he wrote
"(I didn't put the code for `Misses` here for the sake of simplicity)"
so I would assume that there is a similar line for that.

But still, since the issue can't be seen in the code posted thus far, it's a bad idea to not post a seemingly trivial case for us to inspect.

Comment: I need to acknowledge that the given example in the string isn't a very good idea if I only handled 'mister' here in the code in the posting while the string contains `Misses`. Anyway, @CrushaK.Rool is right! I edited the string for this example.

Comment: @Çan I am sorry but I don't get you.  What do you mean? From you posted code I can't see how we could get something else than `-1`. Am I missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you do have text with the word "Mister" in it somewhere; the following code should work:

```
string[] lines = "3.3. 3 - 3 88C Misses Molitor D For Ne Les Text".Split(' ');      
Console.WriteLine(lines.Contains("Mister") || lines.Contains("Misses"));
var idx = Array.FindIndex(lines, l => l == "Misses");

Console.WriteLine(idx);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. Pos has the value of 5. containsOne is true and containsTwo is false.

```
var lines = "3.3. 3 - 3 88C Mister Molitor D For Ne Les Text".Split(' ');
var pos = Array.FindIndex(lines, c => c.Equals("Mister"));

var containsOne = lines.Contains("Mister") || lines.Contains("Misses");
var containsTwo = lines.Contains("Mister") && lines.Contains("Misses");
```

For more information on the FindIndex method have a look at [this page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03y7c6xy(v=vs.110).aspx)